# How can I catch beetles?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Catching beetles on the trees of the Island is a lucrative hobby but I'm finding very often I'll scare off the beetle, sometimes even before I can see them! I've tried tiptoeing close to them by holding A, but sometimes they still run. Some beetles seem to run before others, but I can't really see the pattern yet.

I can't quite figure out how to catch these beetles. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the gist of it:

- **Don't run**. The island is so small there's really no need, and if you're running, certain sensitive (and expensive) beetle types may flee before you can even see them on screen.
- Approach slowly by holding down A. This will slow you down and prep your net so you just release the button to swing. Some bugs can't even be approached without slowing down, and beetles in particular are jumpy, so play it safe.
- When the beetle stops moving, **stop moving**. The beetles have a little "dance" animation they do while they idle on the trees, unlike other tree bugs. If the beetle sits perfectly still for more than a couple frames of animation, it has been alerted to your presence. If you continue moving, the beetle will eventually fly away. Take deliberate steps with pauses every couple steps, and stop immediately if the beetle seems to pause. Wait for movement before taking another step or two.
- Different beetles have different sensitivities. Horned Dynastids you can practically walk right up to and touch before they'll run. Horned Elephant Beetles will run *extremely* quickly unless you time your steps well, guided by the above advice. You will learn the beetle's sensitivities over time.
- Chase away the fruit beetles (green little bugs) they're worth nothing. Don't even bother, except to fetch a single one for the museum/encyclopedia.
- The sound of a net hitting something will scare the beetles off. Refrain from catching other, cheaper bugs if near a beetle, that way you won't scare off the more expensive prize.

Comment: I thought the beetle's movement was indicative of it preparing to fly away; not its lack of movement.

Comment: @Fluttershy that's exactly the opposite of what I've consistently seen. Beetles will move back and forth when idle. You can check this by watching them from a full screen distance away, they still wiggle back and forth. They will (briefly) stop moving just before they are about to fly away.

Comment: And what you're describing is exactly the opposite of what I've seen. <_<